# Ionic error when using ion-label - TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting an error in my app. When I use an `ion-item` with `ion-label` + `ion-input / ion-chkbox` i get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null`

When I remove the `ion-label` works fine!

Error Example:

```
<ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-label floating>TEXT HERE</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pageDocument.accept"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Working Example:

```
<ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pageDocument.accept"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Whats is the problem with the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below:

Working [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z2tcqa?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label fixed>TEXT HERE</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="pageDocument?.accept" item-end></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Did not Work :(

Comment: Did you see the stackblitz above? It is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Can it be related to ion-split-pane? I tried to remove de ion-split-pane (it is placed inside the page) and it works!

Comment: You didn't tell anything about `ion-split` on your question. Can you simulate your issue with `stackblitz`? :https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I am sorry for missing this information! But Ia moved the ion-split-pane to app.html file and everything woks fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `pageDocument` is set to null in the beginning of the run? Try using a separate variable:

> ```
> <ion-item no-lines>
>     <ion-label floating>TEXT HERE</ion-label>
>     <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="accept"></ion-checkbox>
> </ion-item>
> ```

Comment: Did not work! :( Even declarating accept = true in the contructor... :(

Comment: Can it be related to ion-split-pane? I tried to remove de ion-split-pane (it is placed inside the page) and it works!